# Flexible normalization of entries in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to manipulate my data frame of raw data before creating a graph. I have observed values in the column "TMED7_normalized", which I would like to normalize. These observed values were collected under different test conditions as indicated in the column "siRNA". Furthermore, observations were collected from different origins as indicated in the column "Blot". What I would like to do now, is to normalize the values of TMED7_normalized always by the value in the row with under the condition of "siCtrol". Besides, I would like to do this for each group of different condition. E.g. it would be: Take the first three entries, normalize them by the fourth. Take entry 5-9, normalize them by the 10th. Any ideas on how to do this in an automated way? Here is my data frame:

```
example_data

 Blot         siRNA           TMED7_normalized
   <chr>        <chr>                      <dbl>
 1 FK01_KW26_02 siRNF5                      2.57
 2 FK01_KW26_02 siRNF170                    2.10
 3 FK01_KW26_02 siRNF5_siRNF185             2.24
 4 FK01_KW26_02 siCtrol                     1.81
 5 FK01_KW27_01 siRNF5                      2.36
 6 FK01_KW27_01 siRNF170                    1.64
 7 FK01_KW27_01 siHrd1                      2.66
 8 FK01_KW27_01 siRNF5_siHrd1               2.09
 9 FK01_KW27_01 siRNF170_siHrd1             2.53
10 FK01_KW27_01 siCtrol                     1.13
# ... with 24 more rows
```

Each idea and help would be deeply appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by normalizing, you mean divide the value of `TMED7_normalized` for each test by the respective control?

You can do that using `dplyr`.

```
example_data %>% 
  group_by(Blot) %>%
  mutate(TMED7_normalized = TMED7_normalized / TMED7_normalized[siRNA == "siCtrol"])
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   Blot [2]
   Blot         siRNA           TMED7_normalized
   <chr>        <chr>                      <dbl>
 1 FK01_KW26_02 siRNF5                      1.42
 2 FK01_KW26_02 siRNF170                    1.16
 3 FK01_KW26_02 siRNF5_siRNF185             1.24
 4 FK01_KW26_02 siCtrol                     1   
 5 FK01_KW27_01 siRNF5                      2.09
 6 FK01_KW27_01 siRNF170                    1.45
 7 FK01_KW27_01 siHrd1                      2.35
 8 FK01_KW27_01 siRNF5_siHrd1               1.85
 9 FK01_KW27_01 siRNF170_siHrd1             2.24
10 FK01_KW27_01 siCtrol                     1
```

If you want to do some different operation to normalize, then edit my code appropriately. After you`group_by(Blot)`, use `mutate()` with `TMED7_normalized` to represent the current position and `TMED7_normalized[siRNA == "siCtrol"]` to  represent the control value for each group.

Comment: very nice! thank you for your quick help. it worked very nicely

Comment: @AnnaKo - if the answer is helpful, consider upvoting or accepting it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).